# Fastlane command not found

Tags: xcode, macos, fastlane

I am trying to install `fastlane`. I have Xcode installed. I installed `fastlane` using the command `sudo gem install fastlane`. I now go into my project folder and type `fastlane init` and get the error:

> -bash: fastlane: command not found.

I see that `fastlane` is installed and can see it here

> /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.70.0/bin

on my Mac.

I tried adding this to my `PATH`, but I still get the same error.  My path is

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:./Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you reopen the terminal after the installation? Maybe try to `source ~/.bash_profile`. If there's still problem, add `/Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.70.0/bin` to your PATH.

Comment: Wow. This solved the issue. Thanks much Wang. I have tried adding /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.70.0 this to my PATH earlier and it never worked before. Thanks for this fix buddy. Saved me a ton of time. Wish I could make this the accepted answer

Comment: Keep in mind that if you include a path like /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.70.0 in your PATH, you will have to remember to change that each time you update fastlane to a new version. Ruby should be managing the process of making gem-provided commands available, so I would seek out  a solution that fixes your Ruby setup.

Answer (score 57):

Add the following line to your bash profile:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"
```

You can either close the terminal session and restart it or run `source ~/.bash_profile` to load your configuration and then you can go so you start using fastlane.

Answer (score 49):

I got run into similar issue last week. I installed fastlane using homebrew on mac, but it was showing the same error.

I tried installing it using Ruby and it worked like a charm. Here is the command.

```
sudo gem install fastlane -NV
```

Also seems like you have not installed command line tools for xcode.

Install them using `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Got the same story, error after brew installation, and everything works after Rubi installation!

Answer (score 25):

I met this issue because of installing **[zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)**, the below two steps solve my problem:

1. `open ~/.zshrc`
2. save path

   2.1 if you install fastlane with Homebrew

   Copy `export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"` on the bottom line.

   2.2 if you install fastlane with RubyGems

   Copy `export PATH="/usr/local/bin/fastlane""` on the bottom line.
3. save upon file and try `fastlane init`, everything is OK!

Comment: Some of us don't know `.zshrc`, can you please try to show us where it comes from towards the answer.

Answer (score 17):

1. In the terminal type `cd ~/` to go to your home folder
2. Type `touch .bash_profile` to create your new empty file
3. Type `open -e .bash_profile` to open the file
4. Enter `export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"` and save
5. Restart terminal (not sure needed?)

Answer (score 14):

Here is what I installed on Mac - from scratch

Removed from brew install

`brew uninstall fastlane`

`brew install rbenv`

Install Ruby version 2.6.6

`rbenv install 2.6.6`

Set the Ruby version in global

`rbenv global 2.6.6`

Add Ruby to the PATH

`if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi`

Install bundler

`gem install bundler`

Install fastlane

`bundle add fastlane`

Comment: The problem is when I use brew I get now get cocoapod errors with fastlane.

Answer (score 8):

fastlane is in cask now. You can install it using

```
brew cask install fastlane
```

Now you need to export PATH so that your shell can find fastlane
do

```
export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"
```

If that doesn't work, try this

```
export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin/fastlane_lib:$PATH"
```

Make sure you add it to ~/.profile, ~/.zshrc or ~/.bashrc for future

Answer (score 7):

brew install ruby

brew install fastlane

Warning: fastlane 2.145.0 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link fastlane` to link this version.

brew link fastlane

cd iOS

fastlane init

Answer (score 6):

If you are working on local machine then add following to you .bash_profile

**export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"**

If you are working on Jenkins then this worked for me

Under **Jenkins** -> **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure System** -> **Global properties** -> Environment variables I added:

Name: **Path**
Value: **/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin**

[Reference](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/14179)

Comment: 2 days of banging my head against the wall, ends here. Thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

I have got the same issue on mac `10.11`, after a lot of struggling I found that the problem in installing `unf_ext 0.0.7.2` gem
I have done the following from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35520348/1565971)

```
brew install coreutils
```

After that try reinstall `fastlane` again it should work again

Answer (score 2):

**DO NOT INSTALL FASTLANE GLOBALLY**
It is recommended that you use a Gemfile to define your dependency on Fastlane. This will clearly define the used Fastlane version, and its dependencies, and will also speed up using Fastlane.

Step 1: Install bundler using

`sudo gem install bundler`

so any time you wan run Fastlane
`bundler exec fastlane ...`

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue in `Fedora 30` i followed these steps:-

1-installed all dev tools using these commands

```
sudo dnf install @development-tools
sudo dnf install @rpm-development-tools
```

2- run `sudo gem install fastlane -NV`

`Fastlane` worked like a charm
hope it helped

Answer (score 2):

I managed to install following way

**Install ruby**

```
sudo apt install ruby ruby-dev
```

Add following to top of  your "~/.profile" file

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Check of any errors with `source ~/.profile` command. If there is not output means all is good.

**Install Build essentials**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

**Fastlane depends on Google API Clint lets install that first**

```
sudo gem install google-api-client
```

**Install Fastlane**

```
sudo gem install fastlane -NV
```

**Check your installation**

```
fastlane -v
```

[image: Output Should be like]

Credits: [This](https://dev.to/subbramanil/fastlane-setup-in-ubuntu-2dfb) and [this](https://www.nickagas.com/install-fastlane/) article helped me.

Comment: thanks for your answer I tried it but getting ERROR:  Error installing fastlane:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.8.2/ext/unf_ext
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/ruby -I /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20220913-859-1mzlwgp.rb extconf.rb
extconf failed, exit code 1

Answer (score 2):

**Flutter and Github Actions for Android:**

If you are setting up Github Actions for a Flutter project for android and run into this error in one of your steps, see the work flow below:

```
jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      LC_ALL: en_US.UTF-8
      LANG: en_US.UTF-8
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1

      - name: Setup Fastlane
        working-directory: ./android  # <-- Make sure you have this
        run: bundle install

      - name: Run Fastlane
        working-directory: ./android. # <-- Make sure you have this
        run: bundle exec fastlane android [lane name].
```

Make sure to setup the `ruby/setup-ruby@v1` action correctly depending on your project. see the doc: https://github.com/ruby/setup-ruby

In my case I have not specified the ruby version because I am using the .ruby-version file in my project.

Answer (score 1):

You can add fastlane path environment by add line

```
export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"
```

to `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zsh_profile` file (if you use zsh shell).

And final start new terminal session or reload using command `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.zsh_profile` (if you use zsh shell)

Answer (score 1):

First,You need to check if you have the ~/.fastlane file. If you don't have the file, you can execute ***brew cask install fastlane*** command. If you already have it. Check other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Im my case, I need to add this path to my env, then command is found.

`export PATH="/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/bin:$PATH"`

Try reinstall fastlane, it didn't create `.fastlane` in my $HOME dir.

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.4.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.2.0 (2022-12-25 patchlevel 0) [arm64-darwin21]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/haibozhou/.gem/ruby/3.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /opt/homebrew/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/haibozhou/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - arm64-darwin-21
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0
     - /Users/haibozhou/.gem/ruby/3.2.0
     - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => true
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/bin
     - /Users/haibozhou/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/bin
     - /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin
     - /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/bin
     - /opt/homebrew/bin
     - /opt/homebrew/sbin
```

Answer (score -6):

Get the full path of the fastlane executable from the command line:

`which fastlane`

Add it to the shell profile, restart shell.

Comment: This is more of a comment -- not an answer.