# Fastlane keeps warning that I am using Ruby 2.2.4

Tags: ios, ruby, fastlane

I've updated to Ruby 2.5.5 via `rvm` but I continue to get warnings from Fastlane. For context, I'm building an iOS app on Max OSX and I installed Fastlane via homebrew, `brew cask install fastlane`. I searched online and in the github repo for Fastlane, but couldn't really find a solution.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

And here is the Fastlane output
[image]

There *is* a ruby 2.2.4 located here, which I am presuming Fastlane is using, but it's not clear to me what the proper way to upgrade this is or if there is some environment variable I can set so that Fastlane picks up the newer version.

```
~/.fastlane/bin/bundle/bin/ruby -v
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

How can I get Fastlane to pick up the right version of Ruby?

Alternatively, are these warnings safe to ignore?

**EDIT:**
Here is my `fastlane env` stack

```
| --------------------------- | ------------------------------------------- |
| OS                          | 10.14.6                                     |
| Ruby                        | 2.2.4                                       |
| Bundler?                    | false                                       |
| Git                         | git version 2.22.0                          |
| Installation Source         | ~/.fastlane/bin/bundle/bin/fastlane         |
| Host                        | Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G87)                    |
| Ruby Lib Dir                | ~/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib                  |
| OpenSSL Version             | OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016                  |
| Is contained                | false                                       |
| Is homebrew                 | true                                        |
| Is installed via Fabric.app | false                                       |
| Xcode Path                  | /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ |
| Xcode Version               | 10.3                                        |
```

Comment: What does `fastlane env` give you? That should show where Fastlane is at least looking for Ruby.

Comment: And how are you executing your lane - what command are you running?

Comment: I added the `fastlane env` above. I'm running `fastlane ios alpha`, `alpha` is the name of my lane as defined in my Fastfile. Did that answer your question?

Comment: It's my understanding that the Homebrew installation method bundles that version of Ruby. Have you tried uninstalling from Homebrew and reinstalling using RubyGems? 
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/14212

Comment: @eeekari I haven't tried that, I was hoping to get it to work via homebrew. I'll give it a try

Comment: You either manage Ruby with Homebrew or with RVM - they don't mix.

Comment: Here is what I did for fresh install: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62677836/4185100

Answer (score 1):

When you install fastlane via homebrew it includes its own version of ruby, as you've seen.  But if you install fastlane through `gem install fastlane` it'll pick up the version of ruby from `rvm`.  So the solution in this case is to uninstall fastlane and reinstall it as a gem.  Once you've done that you can run `fastlane env` again and you should see it picking up the expected ruby version.

Thanks to the people on [this thread](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/14212) for the answer.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I spent the last few days with this because it would not update fastlane and this is how I was able to fix it. Here is what I found and what I did that worked for me

Using the sudo command to run install with the `gem` command puts it into the the usr/local/bin folder and you have to have root privileges to update fastlane and you don't want that. Brew bundles an incorrect version of ruby that won't let you update, either. I ended up with two installations that I needed to get rid of and then get things done the correct way. I am running Catalina so I needed to change my `~/.zshrc` file, but I assume changing `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` should do the same for older version of OSX.

You may not have to do all of this, I was angry yesterday and ended up with multiple installs. Just be aware if some of these things don't exist or error out.

Here is what I did:

I uninstalled fastlane from brew `brew cask uninstall fastlane`

I then went into my user folder and deleted the `.fastlane` folder

I ran `fastlane env` to catch my second install and looked at the `Installation Source` and deleted the fastlane command from that location.

I then ran `fastlane` and got No Command Found

Now edit your bash or zshrc file to add

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.gems/bin
export GEM_HOME=~/.gems
```

save, close and restart the terminal

run `gem install fastlane -NV`. DO NOT USE SUDO! It installs back to usr/local/bin and you don't want that. fastlane can't update if you do

once the install finishes, run `fastlane env` and make sure the Install Location is in `~/.gems/..` and if you want, run `fastlane update_fastlane` to make sure you get the Nothing to Update message instead of a waring about needing sudo.

Hopefully this works or helps someone else.